# CONCAT_WS Three Fields to Create PRIMARY KEY in CREATE TABLE Statement

Tags: mysql, concatenation, primary-key, create-table

I'm writing a `CREATE TABLE` statement for a fairly large table which will be loaded via a `.csv` file.

I need to create a `PRIMARY KEY` by concatenating three of the fields together:

- `STORE_NBR`
- `CONTROL_NBR`
- `LINE_NBR`

and append that newly created/named field to the beginning of each record.

Is this possible within the `CREATE TABLE` statement?  Or do I have to use `APPEND`after the fact?

And how would I do that?

EDIT -----  3/21/2016

---

I'm still being told I should be able to concatenate the three fields when creating the table itself, i.e. -

```
CREATE TABLE Mistints(
        CONCAT(storeNbr,controlNbr,lineNbr) AS pKey,
        storeNbr INT,
        controlNbr INT,
        lineNbr INT,
        salesNbr VARCHAR(15) etc etc
```

But I'm getting an error when attempting to do that.  My supervisor wants that concatenated field appended to the beginning of each record and wants it as the Primary Key.  Is there a way to do so within the Create Table statement?  Or do I have to do an Update after the fact?  Or do so as I load the table (via .csv file)?

Comment: Why do you think you need that 3 part PK? What are each of those 3 representing? From usual naming conventions LINE_NBR sounds like a unique 'counter' that could be the PK by itself (set to AUTO_INCREMENT). Then in your query you can use SELECT... CONCAT(STORE_NBR,'-', CONTROL_NBR)... in your query.

Comment: I have very specific guidelines I must follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible through `CREATE TABLE` by adding following lines to the end of your table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE TAB_NAME(
  STORE_NBR [data type]([size]) [column constraint],
  CONTROL_NBR [data type]([size]) [column constraint],
  LINE_NBR [data type]([size]) [column constraint],
  .
  .
  .
  PRIMARY KEY (STORE_NBR, CONTROL_NBR, LINE_NBR)
  );
```

Comment: After further consultation with my supervisor, determined I will actually have to "manipulate" the .csv file first, sorting it and adding the field to each record before I even load it into the table!

Comment: But this gives me a reminder/idea of how to pursue this.  Thank you.

Comment: Still - would I be able to do something like do a create table with those fields, load the table, then follow with a CREATE TABLE AS and SELECT CONCAT (STORE_NBR, CONTROL_NBR, LINE_NBR) AS PKEY, select all the remaining columns and then PRIMARY KEY (PKEY) at the end?